# Boundary of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus

Let $a_n,b_n$ be two sequences with $a_n\geq 1$ and $b_n\geq 1$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$. Define $s:=\sup_n\{a_n,b_n\}$.

I am trying to show that $\frac{1}{1+s}\leq \frac{a_n}{a_n+b_n}\leq \frac{s}{1+s}$. I don’t have any idea on how can I proceed since I cannot compare the denominators.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: use $$\frac{1}{s} \le \frac{b_n}{a_n} \le s$$